# How can hugo copy static directory to `public/static` instead of `public`?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hugo

I'm using `vscode` to write markdown post and using `vscode markdown preview` feature to preview.

When I add a picture to markdown, with the format `![some-pic](/static/img/some-pic.png)`, the preview can show the picture but `hugo` generated html can't, because `hugo` will copy the `static` directory to `public` rather than `public/staitc`.

But with the format `![some-pic](/img/some-pic.png)`, `hugo` generated html is ok but vscode preview is not work for the picture.

So how can I adjust hugo configuration or vscode configuration to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a related issue playing with the option `markdown.extension.completion.root` in vscode. See https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues/548

Hope that helps

Comment: Please summarize your solution instead of just providing a link.